# Roots of a polynomial with great coefficients

Tags: matlab

I have a polynomial that has coefficients that depend on two parameters `x` and `y`and their powers non-linearly. I sweep `x` to find roots of the polynomial for `y`, but for most values of x, the function `roots` gives the error of "Input to ROOTS must not contain NaN or Inf", and when I see the coefficients of the polynomial with the `sym2poly` function, they are `inf`.

I can't change the polynomial because it is gained from a problem, what can I do?

Comment: What root do you want when the polynomial has infinite coefficients?

Comment: In fact Matlab shows them as infinite but they are just very big numbers gained in my computations. can I increase what Matlab defines as infinite?

Answer (score 0):

For practical purposes I can suggest the following work around:

Replace all inf values by a really big positive number, and all -inf values by a big positive number.

For NaNs you can do something similar, but I think NaN is typically not used to replace a big number in Matlab. If you don't care about these points I guess you can just replace them by 0 for example.